# Many unwind segues from a single button

Tags: xcode5, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a modal view which can be presented from 5 different parent view controllers. This modal view has a button which brings you back to the parent VC.

I'm updating to iOS7 and I think it used to be able to use this single button to associate it to all the unwind segues I created. But now, I can only link one single unwind seue to this button.

I'm doing all that (linking one thing to the other) on Storyboard.

Is there any change on the Xcode 5 regarding this issue? I could handle everything on code, but it just bothers me that it doesn't work any more on the GUI.

Any thougths?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue when I was trying to figure out how to unwind a segue from a modal view controller that could be presented from 2 different view controllers.  I found a way to do it that does involve some code but you can do some of it from Storybuilder.

The thing I had to realize was that I could have the same unwind action method signature in two different view controllers.

My app has two view controllers that can present the modal.  The two view controllers are:

HomeScreen
ExploreScreen

The modal view controller is called:

RatingScreen

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html I could unwind from RatingScreen to HomeScreen by putting the following unwind action in HomeScreen.m:

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromRatingScreen:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Unwinding to HomeScreen"); 
}
```

Following Apple's technote I control dragged from my Cancel button on my RatingScreen to its Exit icon.  It allowed me to select unwindFromRatingScreen from the action segue drop-down.  Note, if you don't have at least one unwind action defined in your project you can't even control drag to the Exit button.  It mentions this in the technote but it's not that obvious.

Anyway, I was confused at this point about how to handle unwinding from RatingScreen back to ExploreScreen.  It turned out, all I had to do was put an unwind action with the same signature as the one I put in the HomeScreen.m.  To be clear, I put this unwind action in ExploreScreen.m:

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromRatingScreen:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Unwinding to ExploreScreen");
}
```

I was amazed that this worked because I thought there would be some ambiguity at run-time.  How does iOS know which unwind action to call?  I'm guessing it looks in some stack.  Maybe that's what the technote is trying to say but I couldn't follow it due to my confusion over what terms like "parent" and "presenting" refer to.

I came up with a second solution after reading https://medium.com/@hamderhallas/custom-ios-modal-dismiss-segue-7e21c2bcf690.  I think it might only work for a cancel button.  I don't know if it works for a submit button which needs to obtain state from the modal view controller and use it to set state in the view controller you want to unwind to.  The solution was simply to tell the modal view controller to dismiss itself.  Again, iOS must have a stack of view controllers it can refer to in order to figure out what view controller to show when the modal is dismissed.

This second solution was to put the following method in RatingScreen.m:

```
- (IBAction)cancelAction:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'm very new to iOS development so I'm sure others will have more insightful ideas.  But I found both of these solutions addressed a problem similar to yours.  Sorry I couldn't give you a solution that could be implemented entirely from the Storyboard.  But I hope this helps.